# RSpec Mark Failed Tests as Skipped

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

We have a unit test suite, written in RSpec. We have some failed tests that is a lot actually.

What I am looking for is a script or a magic command, to mark all the failed tests as skipped, so I don't have to go over them one by one and mark them as skipped.

Answer (score 5):

I found this awesome script that do exactly what I need:
https://gist.github.com/mcoms/77954d191bde31d4677872d2ab3d0cd5

Copying the contents here, in case the original gist is deleted:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class CustomFormatter
  RSpec::Core::Formatters.register self, :example_failed

  def initialize(output)
    @output = output
  end

  def example_failed(notification)
    tf = Tempfile.new
    File.open(notification.example.metadata[:file_path]) do |f|
      counter = 1
      while (line = f.gets)
        if counter == notification.example.metadata[:line_number]
          line.sub!('it', 'skip')
          line.sub!('scenario', 'skip')
          @output << line
        end
        tf.write line
        counter += 1
      end
    end
    tf.close
    FileUtils.mv tf.path, notification.example.metadata[:file_path]
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice find! Not sure why someone downvoted this. Maybe because it was link-only answer.

Comment: I'd use `xit` and `xscenario` to keep the information what it was in case you wanna go back with a similar script. If `xscenario` doesn't exists - define it as an alias https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-7/docs/configuration/create-example-aliases#use-symbols-as-metadata

Answer (score 3):

Should be relatively straightforward. RSpec lists failing specs like this

```
rspec ./spec/models/user.rb:67 # User does this thing
rspec ./spec/models/post.rb:13 # Post does another thing
rspec ./spec/models/rating.rb:123 # Rating does something else entirely
```

File name and line number point to the opening line of the test, the one with `it ... do`.

Write a script that

1. extracts file names and line numbers from the failure output
2. opens those files, goes to the specified line
3. and [replaces `it` with `xit`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/pending/pending-examples#temporarily-pending-by-changing-%22it%22-to-%22xit%22).

Comment: I'd estimate this to be a 10 LOC ruby script. 15 LOC tops